# Setting up a Factory Pattern in Go

Tags: go, factory

I have a factory pattern setup at the moment but I'm having trouble getting the returned objects to remember anything when explicitly initialising them.

I have the following files:

carBase.go

```
package Cars

//base class for car factory
type car interface {
  Initialise(string, string)
  SayCar()
}
```

toyota.go

```
package Cars

import (
    "fmt"
)

type toyotaCar struct {
  carType string
  colour string
}

func (car toyotaCar) Initialise(col, carType string){

  car.colour = col
  car.carType = carType

}

func (car toyotaCar) SayCar(){
  fmt.Println(car.carType)
  fmt.Println(car.colour)
}
```

carFactory.go

```
package Cars

func GetCar(carType string) (car) {

  switch carType {
  case "toyota":
    return new(toyotaCar)
  }

  return new(toyotaCar)

}
```

and finally main.go

```
package main

import (
  "FactoryTest/Cars"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {

  car := Cars.GetCar("toyota")
  fmt.Println(car)
  car.Initialise("thing" , "otherthing")
  fmt.Println(car)
  car.SayCar()
  fmt.Println(car)

}
```

In each of the `fmt.Printn(car)` lines, I'm getting `&{ }` which indicates that nothing is being set. When I run `car.SayCar()` nothing prints out.

Am I just trying to force the issue here, or is there something simple that I'm missing to make this work?

Comment: Literally just worked it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with not using pointers with the car being taken in by the methods:

toyota.go becomes:

```
package Cars

import (
    "fmt"
)

type toyotaCar struct {
  carType string
  colour string
}

func (car *toyotaCar) Initialise(col, carType string){

  car.colour = col
  car.carType = carType

}

func (car *toyotaCar) SayCar(){
  fmt.Println(car.carType)
  fmt.Println(car.colour)
}
```